# Disable and enable Selectize Dropdown based on CheckBox

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I am trying to enable and disable Selectize Dropdown depending on Checkbox value. I wrote something that only works for disabling the control. But I cant enable it.

Here is what I tried:

[image]

It shows this error:

[image]

if I comment out  `$('#' + Id)[0].selectize.enable();` this line then disabled functionality works just fine.

Is a work-around available?

Comment: Can you try this one, if this is working for you? Disabled - $('#'+ Id)[0].attr("disabled", "disabled"), Enable - $('#'+ Id)[0].attr("disabled", "false");

Comment: @mksmanjit yes I tried. No effect on Selectize Control. :(

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle for this, if possible?

Comment: Try this one $("PARENT_DIV_ID_OR_CLASS_OF_SELECTIZE").find("input, select").attr("disabled", "disabled");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check if `$('#' + Id)[0].selectize` has value or not. This solved my issue.  Here is full snippet for everyone:

```
function EnableDisablePicker(Instrution, Id) {

    if (Instrution === 'Disable') {

        if ($('#' + Id)[0].selectize) {
            $('#' + Id)[0].selectize.disable();
        }
    }
    if (Instrution === 'Enable') {
        if ($('#' + Id)[0].selectize) {
            $('#' + Id)[0].selectize.enable();
            $('#' + Id)[0].selectize.clear();
        }
    }

}
```